# Custom loss function (focal loss) input size error in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, loss-function, imbalanced-data

I am using a neutral network to do multi-class classification. There're 3 imbalanced classes so I'd like to use the focal loss to handle the in-balance. So I use custom loss function to fit in Keras sequential model. I tried multiple versions of code for focal loss function I found online, but they return the same error message, basically saying the input size is the bath size while expected 1. Could anyone have a look at the issue and let me know if you can fix it? I really appreciate it!!!

```
model = build_keras_model(x_train, name='training1')
```

​

```
class FocalLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, gamma=2., alpha=4.,
             reduction = tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='focal_loss'):

    super(FocalLoss, self).__init__(reduction=reduction,
                                    name=name)
    self.gamma = float(gamma)
    self.alpha = float(alpha)

def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

        epsilon = 1.e-9
        y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true, tf.float32)
        y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, tf.float32)
        model_out = tf.add(y_pred, epsilon)
        ce = tf.multiply(y_true, -tf.math.log(model_out))
        weight = tf.multiply(y_true, tf.pow(
            tf.subtract(1., model_out), self.gamma))
        fl = tf.multiply(self.alpha, tf.multiply(weight, ce))
        reduced_fl = tf.reduce_max(fl, axis=1)
        return tf.reduce_mean(reduced_fl)

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
          loss = FocalLoss(alpha=1),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
​
class_weight = {0: 1.,
            1: 6.,
            2: 6.}
```

​    `# fit the model (train for 5 epochs)
    history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, 
    class_weight = class_weight)`

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 64 for 'loss/output_1_loss/weighted_loss/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [64].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the issue that you are leveraging some helper class that is designed for doing some logic for you, but unfortunately, its documentation is not very clear about *what exactly* it does for you and, hence, *what exactly* you need to do on your own.

In this case you use `tf.keras.losses.Loss`. All you need to do is implement `call()` (and optionally `__init__`). Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) doesn't state at all what it expects `call()` to return. But as you need to specify a `reduction` in `__init__()`, we can assume that `call()` is expected to not only return a single number. Otherwise `reduction` would be useless. In other words: the error is telling you that `call()` returns a single number while it is expected to return 64 numbers (your batch size).

So, instead of reducing the batch into a single number yourself (by calling `tf.reduce_mean(reduced_fl)`), let the helper class do this for you and just return `reduced_f1` directly. Currently you use `reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO` which is likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Keras loss functions take a batch of predictions and training data, and use them to produce a tensor of loss. One way this can be implemented is simply by defining a function with two tensor inputs which returns a number, like so

```
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Then pass this to the model at compilation like so

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss = mse)
```